# Skipping several iterations of for-loop based on condition

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to skip iterations in a for loop based on conditions. Intuitively I thought this would work:

```
for(i in 1:10){
  if(i %in% c(1,2,3,4,5)){
    print(i)
    i <- i+2}
}
```

I would want it to return

```
1
4
```

but instead it returns

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

I am aware why this is happening.

Is there another way to skip (multiple) iterations based on a condition in a for loop in R?

Comment: What's wrong with doing something directly like this? `for(i in 1:10){
  if(i %in% c(1,4)){
    print(i)}
}`. The reason your code isn't working is because by using `i <- i + 2` you aren't actually updating the `i` in the for loop.

Comment: It is bad practice to increment a for loop index inside the loop itself. Makes it very confusing to track things. Either use `while()` and increment inside the loop, or use `for()` and don't increment by hand. Or better (particularly in R): vectorise your code

Comment: Thank you for the comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just bad practice to increment the counter inside the loop in R. It simply will not work. That's not the way the language is built. If you want to get 1 and 4 printed then try:

```
for(i in seq(1,10,by=3) ){
  if(i %in% c(1,2,3,4,5)){
    print(i)
  }
}
```

Do also note that for-loops actually return NULL. There would be a side-effect of printing to the console, but no values of variables would change. If you want values to change you need to do assignment inside the loop.

The is a `next` control statement:

```
for(i in seq(1,10) ){
  if( !(i %in% c(1,4)) ){ next }
  print(i)
}
```

Comment: While this works for this particular little example, it doesn't work for the actual problem I have. I need to skip iterations based on conditions and I don't know beforehand in which iterations these conditions are met.

Comment: There is a `next` control-statement that can skip to the next loop iterator. To find the help page for the `for` and `next statements, then type `?'for'`